# Top 5 feature subsets from feature selection

Tags: python, feature-selection

As i know that feature selection such as forward feature selection give you the best subset of features.
Is there a way to not only find the best subset but also the 2,3,4 and 5th best subset of features to predict? So i can make comparison of top 5 subset of features to predict.

Comment: There are some suggestions here for a more appropriate site for this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.